# Ruby on Rails or PHP... Somehow uncertain

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I've been thinking about this a long time now but I want to hear your opinion because I always receive the best answers here. So any advance... thank you guys.

Right now I have to make this decision:

Shift a prototype webservice to production quality. Choose either Ruby or PHP...
(Background: A friend of mine is joining the project and prefers rails)

I've already played around a bit with RoR (only basic stuff) but I am really disappointed about the documentation of Rails and Ruby. In relation to PHP I find only fragments or hard-to-use references. At the end I am a bit scared. I don't want to waste my time realizing that I am not capable of doing s.th in Ruby what I could with PHP. Maybe only because I am too stupid and don't find a proper explanation ;-)

Did anyone experience this shift and can tell me how easy/hard it was to switch from PHP to Ruby? E.G. would you recommend programming it in PHP and using MVC as a base pattern?

Thanks for your opinion!!!

Comment: Use what you know best and are most comfortable with. Only you can answer that.

Comment: I don't think many languages have a documentation that compares to PHP (maybe Java, but I can't think of many others)

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted up, not really a question...

Answer (score 4):

It's not that hard and the documentation is there, it's just less centralized then PHP's. For a similar documentation style on Ruby and RoR try http://apidock.com - it features a php.net like community driven documentation interface.

Also a great way how to get up to speed with rails is http://railscasts.com. This is a series of screencasts about various rails related topics.

I prefer Rails too - and used to program with PHP before. It definetely has many advantages over PHP, but it is largely a preference thing.

Comment: The Railscasts are really great and help a lot more than reading dry documentation. The Pragmatic Rails book is also a great place to start, even if it is somewhat out of date, especially with Rails 3 on the near horizon.

Comment: +1 for apidock. Also worth mentioning is the excellent documentation of the ruby standard library. 90% of the time confusion about the way rails does something is due to ignorance of how/why ruby does something.

Answer (score 3):

There's no definitive answer what is "the better" choice.

But remember: Rails is not a language, it's a complete framework. If you want to compare things, you have to compare **Ruby with PHP** and **Rails with something like the Zend Framework**.

Comment: Yes most people always get confused about this point. They try to compare RoR and Php instead of comparing Ruby and Php in particular . RoR is a full stack framework then lots of aspects are covered (sql injection, xss ...).  Php is a language .  I like both Php and Ruby especially I love RoR.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should determine for yourself if you're comfortable switching langauges. If you are an advanced developer you may not have problems with the new syntax/paradigm.  However, one thing you might want to consider is what the site is going to be used for and how much traffic you anticipate. I have read articles where RoR has trouble scaling past a certain threshold, etc...  i.e. Twitter.  Also, there are much more OSS components available to PHP if you plan on some code re-use, etc. Like you, I have only played with RoR but some people swear by it. It's sorta like the Mac people out there in a way... I haven't switched myself, but I have read RoR is really easy to use and is very intuitive compared to PHP.

Comment: I don't want to get in a flame war here, but I really think quite a few of the statements you write are (no longer) true.

Scaling is for example a pretty solved issue - many modern Ruby implementations are reaching very fast performance and are getting good at handling many requests concurrently (see eg. Enterprise edition Ruby). Also RubyGems provide much better reusability then many PHP components.

Answer (score 0):

Choose whatever programming language you and your friend feel you can both quickly get up to speed and ship a quality product with in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the first answers... Hmm, it looks like there are really no pros and cons from the technical side ;-) Maybe i get used to the poor documentation in relation to php.